# AsyncStorage callback not working after live reload

Tags: react-native

I've noticed that if I am using `AsyncStorage.getItem()` and I make a change in a file, to trigger a live reload of the application in the emulator, but then at the same time its recompiling the JS, I then save once again, to interupt and trigger a new compilation, then it stops working and requires me to restart the application (react-native run-android again)

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("somekey").then((result) => {

    //After reload, this section never executes

});
```

Is there any fix for this ? or Is there any alternative to `AsyncStorage` ?

Comment: add a catch method and log the error. If you can please paste it.

Comment: the entire callback is not working. I tried it.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you are trying do achieve here. Would you like to save or fetch data whenever the application gets killed?

Comment: @dentemm It's an open issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18372

Answer (score 0):

Switching to async await worked for me:

```
const resolvedPromisesArray = [
        AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY),
];
let token = await Promise.race(resolvedPromisesArray);
```